# How to manage "virtual root" filesystem with perl - sort of "pseudo chroot"

Tags: perl, path, relative-path, filepath, chroot

Looking for a module with a functionality like the perls chroot, but I can't use perl's `chroot` because it needs root privileges. So need something like:

```
#make a new "pseudo chroot"
my $dir = Chroot->new(path => '/some/path');

#change directory
$dir->cd('/tmp'); #the real path will be /some/path/tmp

$dir->pwd;        #returns "/tmp"

$dir->real_pwd;    #returns /some/path/tmp

$dir->cd('/lib')  #now $dir->pwd is /lib - $dir->real_pwd is /some/path/lib
$dir->cd('../../../tmp');

$dir->pwd;        #returns '/tmp' - ignores exceeded ../..
$dir->real_pwd    #returns '/some/path/tmp'
```

and so on...

Questions:

1. Exists such CPAN module? (probably not - I didn't find any)
2. If not, the main question is: *what is the best? (safe and fast) way to ensure than the relative paths like '../../../../some' remains "inside" of pseudo-chroot?*. Exists some module for this?

Ps: No code example yet, because haven't idea how to start - what algorithm is the correct way to ensure than  the `$dir->cd('../../any/long/../..//relative/../../../path')` remains inside the `pseudo chrooted` environment.

EDIT: The `File::Spec->canonpath` doesn't clean the `../..` - by its design. The `Cwd->realpath` is not suitable here, because if the *pseudo chroot* is `/some/path` the simple catenate like, `Cwd->realpath( File::Spec->catpath('/some/path', '../../tmp') )` would return the `/tmp` (it exists) but it is wrong because it is "outside" of the my "pseudo root"... So - no idea yet... ;(

Comment: IMO, the answer to this question is well outside the scope that can be answered in a SO Question. You would *have* to have nasty loads of `XS` code that hooked into, and replaced, Perl's Low-Level IO calls, with indirect IO calls. And this of course, will *NOT* perpetuate outside Perl, so if the user does `system($string)`, the Chroot emulation will be immediately broken.

Comment: And what with `open`, `require`, `mkdir` etc?

Comment: @KentFredric I need a simple "path-cleaning" routie - maybe asked wrongly...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the [File::System](https://metacpan.org/pod/File%3a%3aSystem) module. The [File::System::Real](https://metacpan.org/pod/File%3a%3aSystem%3a%3aReal) is probably for what you're looking. It works with absolute paths, and in the [File::System::Object](https://metacpan.org/pod/File%3a%3aSystem%3a%3aObject) it implemeted an helper method

```
$clean_path = $obj->normalize_path($messy_path)
```

and saying about it:

> Enforces the principle that '..' applied to the root returns the root.
>   This provides security by preventing users from getting to a file
>   outside of the root (assuming that is possible for a given file system
>   implementation).

So, you can use this module directly, or you can chceck how the `normalize_path` is programmed for getting idea how to clean the paths...

Example:

```
use Modern::Perl;
use File::System;
use Data::Dumper::Concise;

my $root = File::System->new("Real", root => '/some/path');
say Dumper $root;

my $file = $root->lookup('/etc/passwd'); #will looking for /some/path/etc/passwd
say Dumper $file;

my $content = $file->content;
say $content;
```

Comment: Going to check it. Thanx.

Answer (score 0):

[http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Spec.html#rel2abs()](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Spec.html#rel2abs%28%29)

Check out rel2abs, it should be able to convert relative path to absolute. After that, you can check with for example a regex if it is inside your pseudo-chrooted dir

Comment: Maybe understand wrong, but the `perl -MFile::Spec -E 'say File::Spec->rel2abs("../../etc/passwd", "/some/path")'` prints `/some/path/../../etc/passwd`. So...